# How can load file to Kendo PDF Viewer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following PDF Viewer in my view, How can I update `pdf.File(Url.Content("~/pdf/test.pdf")` based on the selected project.

```
 <div id="preview">
            
            @(Html.Kendo().PDFViewer().Name("pdfPreview")
                .PdfjsProcessing(pdf => pdf.File(Url.Content("~/pdf/test.pdf")))
                .Toolbar(toolbar =>
                        toolbar.Items(items =>
                        {
                            items.Add().Name("pager");                               
                        })
                    )
                    .Height(701)
                )
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the pdf like so - I can't test this right now, so there may be some typo's but this is based on the example located here: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/pdfviewer/api

```
    $.ajax({
        url: `/product/product/pdfDocumentread?documentID=${documentID}&productID=${productID}`,
        type: 'GET'
    })
    .done(function(data) {
       //here I want to load data.DocumentFilePath to PDF preview
       var pdfViewer = $("#pdfPreview").data("kendoPDFViewer");
       pdfViewer.fromFile(data.DocumentFilePath)
    })
```